# How to replce ony array value with other array value in a specific index?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$a=array([0]=>x [3]=>y);

$b=array([0]=>s [1]=>k  [2]=>m [3]=>z);
```

i want to replace array a's key value s with x and z with Y
output of array will be

```
array([0]=>x [1]=>k  [2]=>m [3]=>y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [**`array_replace()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
<?php
$a=array(0=>'x',3=>'y');
$b=array(0=>'s',1=>'k',2=>'m',3=>'z');
print_r(array_replace($b,$a));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => k
    [2] => m
    [3] => y
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `array_replace` as the other users have suggested.

**OR**

```
<?php
$a=array(0=>'x',3=>'y');
$b=array(0=>'s',1=>'k',2=>'m',3=>'z');
$c=$a+$b;
ksort($c);
print_r($c);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[array_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)** - Replaces elements from passed arrays into the first array

```
<?php
  $a=array(0=>'P',3=>'R');
  $b=array(0=>'s',1=>'k',2=>'m',3=>'z');
  print_r(array_replace($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `union` operator

```
$a = array(0=>'x', 3=>'y');
$b = array(0=>'s', 1=>'k',  2=>'m', 3=>'z');

// union of array $a and $b
$c = $a + $b;
// sort array by key, so output keys are sorted
ksort($c);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($c, true) . '</pre>';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => k
    [2] => m
    [3] => y
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $a=array(0=>'x', 3=>'y');
   $b=array(0=>'s', 1=>'k',  2=>'m', 3=>'z');
   $result = $a+$b;
   ksort($result);
   print_r($result);
?>
```

OutPut:

```
Array ( [0] => x [1] => k [2] => m [3] => y )
```